# Running exe without dll files : Codelite

Tags: c++, dll, static, static-libraries, codelite

I am using code lites with MinGw compiler

I made a basic hello world application however it will not run without these 3 files

These File's are:

libstdc++-6.dll
libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll

How do i Link them to the exe so that they do not need to be with in the same directory as the exe

Comment: Link your executable statically.

Comment: @Steve How do i do that

Comment: Use the `-static` command line option when linking. See [this page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html).